# Not able to loop between songs using pygame.mixer.music

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pygame

```
def selection():
    for song in my_music:
        print(song)
        pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
```

Here `my_music` is list containing the paths of mp3 files that i want to play but, the problem is that it plays only first file though the `my_music` list contains more than 5. I also used `print(song)` to check but it prints the paths of all files but plays only one. can someone help!!

Comment: From the code snippet provided, there is little evidence to go on.  I suspect that the variable my_music is defined somewhere outside of the scope of this function, and this could be part of your problem.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: You probably want to use `.queue()` or `.setendevent()`

Comment: look here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=142142

Answer (score 0):

the `pygame.mixer.music.play()` is not blocking. The songs need to be queued into the mixer and then played. The `loops=x` argument is used to repeat the songs in the queue

```
def play_songs(song_list):
    for song in song_list:
        print("queueing song: {}".format(song))
        pygame.mixer.music.queue(song)
    print("now playing...")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)        # -1 means repeat forever
```